# Show/hide content depending on its data-* attribute with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-post-type

I'm creating a website in WordPress and I'm using the Toolset plugin (Custom fields & post types) to create projects that I display on a project page. All the projects that I create have a category assigned to them (ex. *Complete projects*, *Ongoing projects*), then I have menu objects displaying all categories like *"All Projects", "Completed Projects"* in a row.

I want to be able to display the projects that I have created according to which menu object/name you click on, so all the completed projects should appear when the user clicks on ex. *"Completed Projects"*, *Ongoing Projects* a.s.o.

This is the `div` that gets the `data-category` dynamically assigned  to it (so when I create a project and adds a category to it, it gets added to it):

```
<div class="project_wrapper" data-category="[wpv-post-taxonomy type='category' format='slug']"> <!-- The project code --> </div>
```

This is then the list of menu objects that the user can click on:

```
<div class="project_menu">
 <ul>
  <li id="all" class="objects">All Projects</li>
  <li id="complete" class="objects">Completed Projects</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

This is then the jQuery that should `.hide` or `.show` the corespondig projects depending if the `data-type` that is passed trought it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

 // Show all projects
 $("#all").click(function(){
  $('.project_wrapper[data-category=show-all]').show();
 });

 // Complete projects
 $("#complete").click(function(){
   $('project_wrapper[data-category=complete]').show();
 });

});
```

This is not working at the moment. If I have the parent of the `project-wrapper` set to display `.show` and/or `.hide` it works just fine, but when I pass the `data-*` through the jQuery it doesn't change anything. I'm fairly new to JavaScript and jQuery so sorry if it's a mess. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to show all items that have a `data-category=`,  then use `$("[data-category]")` - otherwise I can't see how `data-category=complete` relates in anyway to `data-category="[wpv-post-taxonomy type='category' format='slug']"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you, if I've understood your question:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

 // Show all projects
 $("#all").click(function(){
  $(".project_wrapper").show();
 });

 // Complete projects
 $("#complete").click(function(){
  $(".project_wrapper").hide();
  $(".project_wrapper[data-category*='completed']").show();
 });

});
```

You were missing a dot in your complete function and I guess you also need to hide all classes before showing only the completed ones.

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/998896/) that you can try with.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps adding quotation marks is going to fix it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // Show all projects
    $("#all").click(function(){
        $('.project_wrapper[data-category="show-all"]').show();
    });

    // Complete projects
    $("#complete").click(function(){
        $('.project_wrapper[data-category="complete"]').show();
    });
});
```

Are the elements hidden to start with? If yes how?

> .show() is roughly equivalent to calling .css( "display", "block" )

**BUT**

> If using !important in your styles, such as display: none !important, .show() will not override !important

So it would be useful to understand what the CSS is like before the function is called.

Comment: Thanks had forgotten that.. But it still dosen't work.

Comment: Yes, I did with the help of this and other threads. Sorry, I forgot to answer it.